# How to inject IServiceContainer when using LighInject?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, light-inject

I am using LightInject and now I need to know how to resolve a type myself. I've tried to use `IServiceContainer`, but when I inject this interface into my class I get an error saying that is an unresolved dependency.

The thing I want te solve is this. At runtime I have a `Type` that I need a instance from. So I want to do something like `SomeResolver.GetInstance(myType)`.

How can I do this with LightInject?

Comment: Make sure you're not abusing the container as [Service Locator](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/).

Comment: @Steven No I'm not. I assembling the query / command type using a Command- or QueryProcessor. When I have the type, I want to get an instance of that type.

Comment: @Martijn Can you include some code to provide a better understanding of what it is you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a working solution. Don't know if this is the 'preferred' way, so if anyone has a better idea, please let me know :)

Here's what I use now:

`container.Register<ITypeResolver>(s => new LightInjectTypeResolver(s));`

And here's the class implementing `ITypeResolver`:

```
public class LightInjectTypeResolver : ITypeResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceFactory _serviceFactory;

    public LightInjectTypeResolver(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        _serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    public object GetType(Type entity)
    {
        return _serviceFactory.GetInstance(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Martijn - I'm in a similar circumstance. What wasn't obvious to me originally was that the overload for container.RegisterType<T>(s => ...) passes in the IServiceFactory in the lambda. Making the move to Autofac and slowly learning :)